# AngularJS Data Binding and Routing not working

Tags: angularjs, data-binding, routes

I am trying to route from Index.html to View1 and from View1 to View2.
But some how , angular data binding and routing isn't working.

Index.html:

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" data-ng-app="purchaseDataApp">
<head>
<title>Index Page</title>
<script src="/Scripts/angular.js"></script>
<script src="controllers/routing.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Index Data</h1>
    <div data-ng-view=""></div>
</body>
</html>
```

View1.html:

```
<body data-ng-controller="PurchaseListController">
<table>
    <tr>
        <td><strong>Name</strong></td>
        <td><strong>Title</strong></td>
        <td><strong>Date</strong></td>
    </tr>
    <tr data-ng-repeat='detail in details'>
        <td><a href="#/view/{{detail.Id}}">{{detail.Name}}</a></td>
        <td>{{detail.Title}}</td>
        <td>{{detail.Date}}</td>
    </tr>
</table>
</body>
```

View2.html:

```
<body data-ng-controller="OrderDetailController">
<div><strong>Name:</strong> {{detail.Name}}</div>
<div><strong>Title:</strong> {{detail.Title}}</div>
<div><strong>Date:</strong> {{detail.Date}}</div>
<div>
    <span data-ng-repeat='dt in details'>{{dt.Name}} </span>
    <div>{{dt.PromotionCode}}</div>
    <div>{{dt.Address}}</div>
    <a href='#/'>Back to order list</a>
</div>
</body>
```

routing.js:

```
var purchaseDataApp = angular.module('purchaseDataApp', []);

function purchaseRouteConfig($routeProvider) {
$routeProvider.
    when('/', {
        controller: PurchaseListController,
        templateUrl: 'Routing/View1.html'
    }).
    when('/view/:id', {
        controller: OrderDetailController,
        templateUrl: 'Routing/View2.html'
    }).
    otherwise({
        redirectTo: '/'
    });
}

purchaseDataApp.config(purchaseRouteConfig);
var details = [{
    Id: 1,
    Name: 'Ray Radulvich',
    Title: 'Beginning with C#',
    Date: 'Dec 30, 2013 12:32:00',
    PromotionCode: 'BSGGS9382',
    Address: '756 E Oak ST, LA, CA- 90565'
    },
    {
    Id: 3,
    Name: 'Samantha Stivens',
    Title: 'Pro ASP>Net MVC Framework',
    Date: 'Apr 3, 2013 03:38:00',
    PromotionCode: 'JDUDUD9678',
    Address: '5443 E Northway ST, LA, CA- 90343'
    }, {
    Id: 6,
    Name: 'Melissa James',
    Title: 'JQuery UI 1.7',
    Date: 'Sep 8, 2013 12:32:00',
    PromotionCode: 'FDTERE5355',
    Address: '8676 Truxel Rd ST, LA, CA- 90542'
    }];

purchaseDataApp.controller('PurchaseListController', function ($scope) {
$scope.details = details;
});

purchaseDataApp.controller('OrderDetailController', function ($scope, $routeParams) {
$scope.detail = details[$routeParams.Id];
});
```

Issues:

1) Index.html shows blank page, ideally it should display View1.html - it just displays-

```
Purchase Data
```

2) When i go to View1.html, it doesn't show anything- displays

```
Name    Title   Date
{{detail.Name}} {{detail.Title}}    {{detail.Date}}
```

There might be some issue which i am not able to figure out- either it is data binding/ routng
Any help on this is much appreciated!

Thanks,
Kan

**Tried the below ones:**

Ideally i have Index.html in Routing folder and view1.html and view2.html in Routing/Partials.

so i have a confusion in routing. I am doing the below code, but it isn't working. Is this correct?

```
var purchaseDataApp = angular.module('purchaseDataApp', ['ngRoute']);

purchaseDataApp.config(function ($routeProvider, $locationProvider) {
$routeProvider.
    when('/Partials/view1', {
        controller: 'PurchaseListController',
        templateUrl: 'view1.html'
    }).
    when('/view/:id', {
        controller: 'OrderDetailController',
        templateUrl: 'Partials/view2.html'
    }).
    otherwise({
        redirectTo: '/Partials/view1'
    });

$locationProvider.html5Mode(true);
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `View1.html` and `View2.html` should be partial pages not a **Page** like `Index.html`

The `View1.html` page should contain only the `HTML` that relates your `PurchaseListController` like

```
<div data-ng-controller="PurchaseListController">
..
</div>
```

and similarly `View2.html`

```
<div data-ng-controller="OrderDetailController">
..
</div>
```

Create your controller like

```
purchaseDataApp.controller('PurchaseListController', function ($scope) {
   $scope.details = details;
  //others code..
});

purchaseDataApp.controller('OrderDetailController', function ($scope, $routeParams) {
    $scope.detail = details[$routeParams.Id];
    //others code...
});
```

In `routeProvider` put the controller name

```
controller: 'PurchaseListController'
```

**Edit**

You missed to include [ngRoute](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngRoute) module. Check the working <kbd>[**Demo**](http://plnkr.co/edit/rmcKsYbWkzT13qsG13Jz?p=preview)</kbd>

**Edit**

You are using [$locationProvider](http://docs.angularjs.org/guide/dev_guide.services.$location), In routing it has two mode

- $locationProvider.html5Mode(true) //HTML5 mode
- $locationProvider.html5Mode(false) //Hashbang mode (default value)

If you use `html5Mode(true)` then your url looks like`www.abc.com/somepage`

And if you use `html5Mode(false)` then your url looks like`www.abc.com/#/somepage`

For `HTML5 mode` you need to configure your server so that it can support otherwise routing will not work.

Comment: Edited the original question as per your comments, however i still see the same issue..Any thought?

Comment: Hi @Reza , Thanks for the help.Still i am having issues.Posted the query to my original question - **Tried the below ones** section

Comment: Check my updated answer, explained about `html5` mode

Comment: Hi @Reza, How can i make sure if the server is set to HTML5 mode? Is i adding below ones in the html page?
<!DOCTYPE html>
<meta charset=UTF-8>

Comment: **NO** those lines are not gonna help you ! To support `HTML5 mode` depends on your server (Apache or IIS or whatever server you use)  you need to rewrite your `URL`.

Comment: Thanks @Reza, i did add- html5Mode(false) and it's working fine.